# how to get input size with fgets?

Tags: c

I have a problem with checking the size of input string with fgets. what I wanted to do is

If the input size is bigger then the buf_len then set "more" to 1 else 0 .

but I am not sure what is the right way to check the input size.

```
int read_stdin(char *buf, int buf_len, int *more)
{    // buf = malloc(10), buf_len = 10 , more = 1,

    fgets(buf, buf_len, stdin) ;
    size_t input_buf_len = strlen(buf);
    printf("size of input: %zu \n",sizeof(input_buf_len)); // prints 8
    printf("buf: %lu \n",sizeof(buf)); // prints 8
    printf("buf_len:%lu \n",sizeof(buf_len)); // prints 4
    printf("stdin:%lu \n",sizeof(stdin));// prints 8
        if (input_buf_len > buf_len)
        {
            *more = 1;
            printf("buf > buf_len\n");
        }
        *more = 0;
         printf("buf < buf_len \n");
     return sizeof(buf);
}
```

it does not matter how big the input length is , could be 1 or 20 , still prints the same number as the comment in the code.

Comment: This if statement if (input_buf_len > buf_len) does not make a sense. input_buf_len can not be greater than buf_len due to this call fgets(buf, buf_len, stdin) ;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I want "more" set to 1 if the input size is bigger than the buf size , what is a better way to do it then?

Comment: Why are you printing `sizeof(input_buf_len))` instead of just printing the value of `input_buf_len`?  Clearly the size of a size_t is not going to change based on the input.

Comment: You don't know whether the input has more data until `fgets` returns `NULL`. If the buffer after reading ends with a newline character, and `fgets` did not return `NULL` then you might read again and receive more input. If it returned and the entire buffer is filled, and it doesn't end in a newline, it may be that you may read again, or that coincidentally the end of the input was reached. If `feof` returns `NULL`, you need to use `feof` and `ferror` to check whether there is no more input or whether an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets()` reads user input and stops when it reads a newline character. It returns:

- A pointer to the string read if it succeeds
- `NULL` if it fails or if it encounters an `EOF`

To get input size, first you have to replace `\n` by a null-terminator, then call `strlen()`. This is because `strlen()` stops when it encouters a null-terminator, but doesn't when it encounters a newline:

```c
if (!fgets(buf, buf_len, stdin)) {
    // fgets failed...
} else {
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
    size_t input_buf_len = strlen(buf);
    printf("Input length: %ld", input_buf_len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fgets` call reads text up to a newline and includes the newline in the read text.  If what was read by `fgets` does not end in a newline character, that means that there's more text to be read on that line.

If `fgets` returns NULL, that means it reached EOF and that no characters have been read.

Comment: If `fgets` returns NULL, that means that either EOF was reached or an error occurred.  You cannot know which happened without calling `feof` or `ferror`.